# No graphical login screen after installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm a senior, so please, no sarcastic answers.  I don't understand Ubuntu and won't have time in life to learn it but I love using it and am amazed I put it on a computer last year to replace Vista and had no problems.  Now, I wanted to put it on an Asus netbook instead of discarding it and it was not the same easy experience. To summarize, I installed it from a DVD I burned and as I did not understand any of the questions, 4th try was a charm.  It said it was installed.

However, when I turn it on after entering my password as the hard disk is locked, and after many pages streaming by, I have a page that welcomes me, talks about packages that can be updated, etc., the final item being my username@ubuntu(name I chose), a colon, a squiggly symbol and a $ followed by a blinking cursor. Nothing on the page can be changed.  Enter just causes that last line to repeat over and over.  Why can't I log in?  I'm eying the garbage pail as I type this. Now, I've had to struggle just to ask a question because my tag is not good enough.

Comment: Have you by any chance maybe downloaded the server image of Ubuntu :) ? There it is normal that you have nothing more than a command line, however that can be fixed easily if this is the case.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Can we please have more info, eg. what version of Ubuntu, what model netbook (I have an 'asus eepc 1000he' which I read from the base on a worn-out label).  The final thing you saw was the BASH or terminal/command prompt which means you are logged in, its just not a "gui" (graphic user interface) you were expecting.

Comment: fyi:  My netbook has only 1gb of ram ([dynamic] memory) so I'd not try Ubuntu (16.04 with Unity or 17.10 with Gnome) as even if it installed & ran; i'd not call it a happy experience.  Mine also is a non-PAE atom cpu (old 32bit only) so the best bet for my eeepc was Lubuntu (14.04 or 16.04) which runs well and does what I want from it.  If you used the minimal or server versions of Ubuntu they by default have no gui, but can be added.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple principles for interacting with a computer. One of them is to use a *graphical user interface* ("point and click"), like you're probably accustomed to and expected to see on your netbook.

Another interaction principle is a *text interface*, also called a command line. That's what you are seeing. Your netbook is expecting you to type a command, to which it would answer with a text output of its own, and so forth.

Ubuntu generally comes with a GUI (multiple GUIs to choose from, actually) *and* a text interface (again, multiple shells to choose from). For some reason, either the installer was unable to install a GUI, or the netbook can't start it up.

It's hard to diagnose the exact cause remotely. Maybe you accidently used the server version of Ubuntu like Videonauth suggested in his comment to your question. Maybe the netbook isn't powerful enough to handle the default GUI, so it uses the text interface as a fallback. Maybe the netbook uses some kind of exotic/unusual hardware that Ubuntu doesn't know how to operate. Those are just some of the possible reasons.

My advise would be visit a Linux User Group in your area, so an experienced Linux user can have a look at your netbook "in person". You can find a local LUG on [ugslist.com](http://lugslist.com) or just by searching for "Linux User Group my-city" (with my-city replaced by your city, of course ;) ).